# iPhone app to point me back to a waypoint (like a computer game)

Tags: iphone, applications, gps, compass

I'm looking for an app which I can use to find my camper in the desert after going for a walk, or find the b&b i left my bags in after exploring a new city. I'm hoping for something really simple which just points in the right direction and perhaps tells me a distance, like your next target on a computer game. I'm imagining opening a compass and clicking a button to record a place then having a needle pointing north and another arrow point back to the waypoint.

Does this exist?

Comment: That's funny because I had the EXACT same idea, and I started developing an app just like that, which doesn't have the bloated features of a full-fledged GPS app like MotionX GPS.

Answer (score 3):

[Motion-X GPS Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=293935935&mt=8) is free, and lets you set waypoints and navigate back to them.  [Reviewed here](http://www.adventure-journal.com/2009/02/outdoor-iphone-apps/).

1. Tap Menu > Waypoints to save or select a waypoint
2. Tap Menu > Compass to see the heading

[image]

Comment: This is no longer free.

Answer (score 1):

[Beacon](http://www.freshapps.com/beacon/) does exactly this and is free.

Comment: This no longer exists.